# Managing Running Scripts in the Background after logging out and logging in

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I know how I can use `CTRL-Z` and `bg` to run a script in the background, and then `fg <number>` to bring it back by its number in `jobs`. However, after logging out and logging back in, `jobs` does not show this information. `ps aux | grep` still shows that the script is running. How can I still manage scripts and bring them back into the foreground after I have logged out and then logged back in, all through terminal?

Also, if I have sent a script into the background and then logged out, and it runs into an error sometime, how will I find out about the error after logging back in?

Comment: Use screen or similar. see https://www.rackaid.com/blog/linux-screen-tutorial-and-how-to/

Comment: From what I see, the only thing I can do is have multiple screens.

Comment: Or run your scripts as a daemon.

Comment: How exactly can I do that?

Comment: Depending on the version of Ubuntu, you write an upstart or systemd boot (init) script.

Comment: upstart or systemd ? post your script. You are not really giveing enough information - https://coreos.com/docs/launching-containers/launching/getting-started-with-systemd/ and https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System_Administrators_Guide/sect-Managing_Services_with_systemd-Unit_Files.html and ask a more specific question ;)

Comment: I'm sorry but I really have no experience with Linux and all.

Comment: so then screen is by far the easiest. otherwise you have not posted much information on your script or what you have tried, so difficult to give advice.

Comment: Ok, I will look into using screen. Thank you. But quick question: So do I install screen on my server and then when running ssh I run screen, or how do I use it? The page you gave me wasn't very clear. And can you write all this as an answer rather than a comment?

Comment: You can re-dierct error messages to a log file. http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-redirect-error-output-to-file/ but your script may or may not continue to run in the background when you log out, thus start with screen.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29865/discussion-between-rohan-and-bodhi-zazen).